# Berry identification help please

Tags: identification, berries

[image]

Hi, could someone please tell me what these are?

Comment: Welcome Antonia! Would you please give us some more information? Where do you live? Is this a low-growing plant? It looks like it's an edging against a brick. Is that the case? We ask all these questions so people can give you the most help. Instructions for the best way to write an identification question are  [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/identification/info). Since our site is different from some others, I invite you to check out our [help]. Please leave us a note if you need help with any functions of the site. Have fun!

Answer (score 4):

The plant is Aucuba japonica 'Serratifolia', or a very similar cultivar.

Take a look at [this link](http://www.artsnursery.com/catalog/aucuba/aucuba-serratifolia-6761), or elsewhere to double check.

Comment: @Antonia You are welcome! If you think the answer is right, can you please mark it as such by clicking at the checkmark at the top (left) of the answer?

Comment: I'm not really sure it is a serratifolia. It could be just a "defect". Leaves on background (I assume from other branches) are "classical" Aucuba japonica.

Comment: @Giacomo But why dont you than post your own answer "This is an aucuba with defect", instead of commenting my answer?

Comment: @VividD: Because you have a short answer, and my answer would be shorter. I doesn't like such short answers. I think your answer and comments are visible enough for users. No night to fight for reputation points.